# How did the Weasley parents get home from King's Cross in Chamber of Secrets?

Tags: harry-potter

While re-reading Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, I came across a small detail that I missed last time. Since the Weasley family came to King's Cross in the flying Ford Anglia, and Ron and Harry took the car after they missed the Hogwarts Express, how did Arthur and Molly get back home? Maybe this is addressed in Ron's howler?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Harry actually has this same exact thought, and Ron tells him his parents can just Apparate.

> “But your Mum and Dad…” said Harry, pushing against the barrier again in the vain hope that it would give way. “How will they get home?”
>
> “They don’t need the car!” said Ron impatiently. “They know how to Apparate! You know, just vanish and reappear at home! They only bother with Floo powder and the car because we’re all underage and we’re not allowed to Apparate yet.…”

EDIT: To clarify, this exchange only occurs in the American version, but is considered canon.

Comment: Ah, should have kept reading before I asked! :) Well done, anyway! Thanks!

Comment: Oh... No wonder I couldn't find it... It's not in the UK version: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106986/what-is-the-provenance-of-this-harry-potter-and-the-chamber-of-secrets-quote

Comment: And they won't bother checking for car.

Comment: @Zikato, what do you mean? That they'd apparate from the platform without seeing if the car was still where they parked it?

Comment: @MacCooper Maybe they just use Accio whenever they want to get the car.. too much of a hassle to remember where it was parked

Comment: @user2813274 haha maybe. Must admit driving back is a hell of a hassle (though making a car fly across London and God knows where else to the Burrow isn't exactly responsible) but yeah was just wondering if Zikato was suggesting that was their plan (if its canon it would add to the answer I think)

Answer (score 12):

dug up by candiedmango

> “They don’t need the car!” said Ron impatiently. “They know how to Apparate! You know, just vanish and reappear at home! They only bother with Floo powder and the car because we’re all underage and we’re not allowed to Apparate yet.…”

The howler simply states how furious Mr and Mrs weasley were when they found the car gone, and brought up how Mr. weasley is in trouble at work.

> "STEALING THE CAR, I WOULDN'T HAVE BEEN SURPRISED IF THEY'D EXPELLED YOU, YOU WAIT TILL I GET HOLD OF YOU, I DON'T SUPPOSE YOU STOPPED TO THINK WHAT YOUR FATHERAND I WENT THROUGH WHEN WE SAW IT WAS GONE -
>   - LETTER FROM DUMBLEDORE LAST NIGHT, I THOUGHT YOUR FATHER WOULD DIE OF SHAME, WE DIDN'T BRING YOU UP TO BEHAVE LIKE THIS, YOU AND HARRY COULD BOTH HAVE DIED -
>   -ABSOLUTELY DISGUSTED - YOUR FATHER'S FACING AN INQUIRY AT WORK, IT'S ENTIRELY YOUR FAULT AND IF YOU PUT ANOTHER TOE OUT OF LINE WE'LL BRING YOU STRAIGHT BACK HOME."

the boys themselves dont mention it at all, they just assume the Weasleys are stuck

> "It's gone," said Ron, sounding stunned. "The train's left. What if
>   Mum and Dad can't get back through to us? Have you got any Muggle
>   money?"

Comment: Ah yes! Of course! I should have thought of that. Me and my silly muggle logic.

Answer (score 9):

According to HP5, Mr Weasley normally apparates to work. The decision to take the car was something of an eccentric treat for the family, which is why the boys seem to have decided that there were no consequences in stranding the Weasley parents in Central London:

> ‘You don’t normally walk to work, do you?’ Harry asked him, as they
>   set off briskly around the square.
>
> ‘No, I usually Apparate,’ said Mr Weasley, ‘but obviously you can’t,
>   and I think it’s best we arrive in a thoroughly non-magical fashion …
>   makes a better impression, given what you’re being disciplined for …’

We also know that Mrs Weasley is capable of apparating.